# Connecting to Google Cloud SQL from Container Engine: can't resolve cloud sql proxy

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to connect to Google Cloud SQL from a node app, which is running in a Google Container Engine pod managed by Kubernetes. I've followed the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/container-engine-connect) to create a Cloud SQL proxy.

When I run the app, I receive:

```
{
    "code": "ENOTFOUND",
    "errno": "ENOTFOUND",
    "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
    "hostname": "127.0.0.1:3306",
    "host": "127.0.0.1:3306",
    "port": 3306,
    "fatal": true
}
```

So it looks as though the proxy can't be resolved.

I've run `kubectl describe pods <pod_name>` and the proxy appears to be healthy:

```
cloudsql-proxy:
    Container ID:   docker://47dfb6d22d5e0924f0bb4e1df85220270b4f21e971228d03148fef6b3aad6c6c
    Image:      b.gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.05
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:338793fcb60d519482682df9d6f88da99888ba69bc6da96b18a636e1a233e5ec
    Port:       
    Command:
      /cloud_sql_proxy
      --dir=/cloudsql
      -instances=touch-farm:asia-east1:api-staging=tcp:3306
      -credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json
    Requests:
      cpu:          100m
    State:          Running
      Started:          Sat, 01 Oct 2016 20:38:40 +1000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:      0
    Environment Variables:  <none>
```

The only thing that seems unusual to me is that the `Port` field is blank, however there was no instruction in the guide referenced above to expose a port in the deployment config file. I've also tried specifying the 3306 port in the configuration file, but although the port then shows in the `kubectl describe pods` output, node still can't find the proxy.

What am I missing here? Why can't I resolve the proxy?

**Edit (more info)**

Logs from the cloudsql-proxy container:

```
2016-10-01T11:44:40.108529344Z 2016/10/01 11:44:40 Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 for touch-farm:asia-east1:api-staging
2016-10-01T11:44:40.108561194Z 2016/10/01 11:44:40 Ready for new connections
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are specifying the host as `127.0.0.1:3306` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Facepalm. I was thrown off by what was written in the tutorial. Thanks!