# Rails 5, Google Container Engine and Google Cloud SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to connect a Rails app deployed in Google Container Engine to a database hosted in Google Cloud SQL.

I'm following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-container-engine). According to it, my pods have two containers: spike and cloudsql-proxy.

In this page, we can read the following line:

> Provide 127.0.0.1:3306 as the host address your application uses to access the database.

At the very end of the process, I get this:

Return of `kubectl logs [pod_name] cloudsql-proxy`

```
2017/05/03 09:50:43 Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 for [instance_connection_name]
2017/05/03 09:50:43 Ready for new connections
```

And in `kubectl exec -it  [pod_name] -- /bin/bash`, return of `cat log/production.log`

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:3306' (25))
```

Isn't it fun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found inspiration in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39824709/3219759).

Turns out that in database.yml, instead of

```
production:
 host: 127.0.0.1:3306
```

it should be

```
production:
 host: 127.0.0.1
```